# setOnItemClickListener gives errors in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-adapterview

I try to get a finish of this activity with a simple click on the full image. Then it should return to the gridview activity, from where it was selected.
But i just cant get it to code, eclipse keeps telling me 
[ The method setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}) is undefined for the type ImageView ] on the setOnItemClickListener.

Here the activity of the fullscreen image:

```
package com.sjapp.picsnd4;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.view.View;
public class FullImageActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

    // get intent data
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // Selected image id
    int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);

    ImageView fsImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fullimage_id);

    fsImage.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v,
    int position, long id) {

    finish();
    }
    }); 

}

}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

use `onClickListener()` for imageView, `onItemClickListener` is for views like ListView, gridView etc..

Answer (score 1):

ImageView is not an AdapterView.
Just use View.onClickListener. it will work.